# Analytic expression for a definite integral containing a trigonometric function and a power of x

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions

I need to calculate the following definite integral:

\begin{align}
I = \int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\pi^2-x^2}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-a\cos^{2}\frac{x}{2}}}} dx
\end{align}
where $a$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$.

Is there an analytic expression for this integral (for example, in terms of some special functions of a)? Wolfram Mathematica failed to give me any answer.

Comment: Using the expansion to $O\left(b^{2001}\right)$, for $b=1$ the value is $43.1219$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that, beside the cases where $a=0$ or $a=1$, there is no explicit solution for this definite integral; the problem is that $0 < a <1$ !

However, if
$$I(a)=\int_0^\pi\frac{\pi ^2-x^2}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-a \cos ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}}\, dx$$ it seems that a reasonable approximation could be given by something like
$$I(a)=\frac {\alpha - \beta\, a}{\sqrt a}$$

A linear regression gives, with  $R^2=0.999994$,
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha & 47.6698 & 0.0146 & \{47.6407,47.6988\} \\
 \beta  & 3.72710 & 0.0469 & \{3.63400,3.82019\} \\
\end{array}$$

For $a=1$, this would give $I(1)\sim 43.9427$ while the exact value is $I(1)=43.1195$ which is the numerical value of
$$\frac{1}{8} \left(896 \sqrt{2} \zeta (3)+8 \sqrt{2} \pi ^2 \left(\log \left(3-2
   \sqrt{2}\right)-3 i \pi \right)+(1-i) \psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)-(1+i) \psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)-(1-i) \psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right)+(1+i) \psi
   ^{(2)}\left(\frac{7}{8}\right)\right)$$

The approximation is very good for small values of $a$. So, using $a=b^2$ and expanding as a series built around $b=0$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-b^2 \cos ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n(x)\, b^{2n-1}$$ The first of these functions is
$$F_0(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\cos (x)+1}}$$ For $1 \leq n \leq 8$ they are odd powers of $\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and, for $n \geq 9$ they are even powers of $\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ divided by $\sqrt{1+\cos (x)}$.

The computation of the definite integrals
$$J_n=\int_ 0^\pi (\pi^2-x^2)\cos ^{2 n+1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx \quad \text{and}\quad K_n=\int_ 0^\pi (\pi^2-x^2)\frac{\cos ^{2 n}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\cos (x)+1}}\,dx$$ do not present any problem (thanks to Wolfram Alpha) and the final result write
$$I(a)=\frac{28 \sqrt{2} \zeta (3)}{b}-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\alpha_n}{\beta_n} b^{2n+1}$$ The first coefficients are given below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & {\alpha_n} & {\beta_n}\\
 0 & 4 & 1 \\
 1 & 25 & 27 \\
 2 & 1813 & 4500 \\
 3 & 461747 & 2058000 \\
 4 & 285567139 & 2000376000 \\
 5 & 30050088913 & 304285766400 \\
 6 & 18059147415499 & 249579242744832 \\
 7 & 13141453098161 & 237694516899840 \\
 8 & 55563794154986291 & 1273956176213360640 \\
 9 & 19575535815512966389 & 554797803977615278080 \\
 10 & 1608205297319647165903 & 55206649171187932594176 \\
 11 & 1991247300342258043248715 & 81418097026162857681616896 \\
 12 & 9371208288978433635255412703 & 450014992066376339226624000000
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $b=1$, the above gives
$$28 \sqrt{2} \zeta
   (3)-\frac{33988692851436059475103482406057}{5613487011035978455512907776000
   \sqrt{2}}=43.3176\cdots$$  still too high but, taking more terms, it should converge.